# Apex Generation Failed while importing wsdl

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to generate Apex classes from a wsdl file.but i am facing a problem...

Apex Generation Failed
Unable to find schema for element; {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string

Can you please help on that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://eapisws.cbp.dhs.gov/ws/manifest1_0/" xmlns:mns="http://eapisws.cbp.dhs.gov/ws/manifest1_0/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://eapisws.cbp.dhs.gov/ws/manifest1_0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mns="http://eapisws.cbp.dhs.gov/ws/manifest1_0/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1_0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                This is the first release of WSDL file for the APIS FlightManifest Batch Web Service and it is subject to change.
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:element name="flightManifest" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Valid UN-EDIFACT document</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="2097152"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="certificationFlightManifest" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Valid UN-EDIFACT document to be certified/validated</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="2097152"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="submissionResponse" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="flightManifestRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="mns:flightManifest" name="flightManifest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="certificationFlightManifestRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="mns:certificationFlightManifest" name="certificationFlightManifest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="flightManifestResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="mns:submissionResponse" name="submissionResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="EapisManifest">
        <wsdl:operation name="submitFlightManifest">
            <wsdl:input message="mns:flightManifestRequest" name="flightManifestRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="mns:flightManifestResponse" name="flightManifestResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="submitCarrierCertificationRequest">
            <wsdl:input message="mns:certificationFlightManifestRequest" name="certificationFlightManifestRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="mns:flightManifestResponse" name="flightManifestResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="EapisManifestSoapBinding" type="mns:EapisManifest">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="submitFlightManifest">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="flightManifestRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="flightManifestResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="submitCarrierCertificationRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="certificationFlightManifestRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="flightManifestResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="EapisManifestService">
        <wsdl:port binding="mns:EapisManifestSoapBinding" name="EapisManifest">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="https://eapisws.cbp.dhs.gov/apis/eapisws1_0/services/EapisManifest"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you provide some information about the wsdl file? Is it a publicly available one or can you post part of it up?

Comment: I think the solution at http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Please-help-me-wsdl2apex-Unable-to-find-schema-for-element/td-p/124631 will give some insight. I think you need to change the element <xs:element name="submissionResponse" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>  to have a complex type.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with the comment in the link posted by pbattisson that "In the end, you may find to get it working that the HTTP request and manual soap xml codeup to be the quickest solution to get it running...it was really faster in the end for me.". I had the same experience. Manually creating a class has been faster for me too.

Comment: Thank a lot pbattisson.... for helping me....i got the solution by changing complexType...

Comment: Will add that as the answer for you to mark for people to view in future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is mentioned in the comment made regarding changing the submission response element from a simple type to a complex type as mentioned in the [link](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Please-help-me-wsdl2apex-Unable-to-find-schema-for-element/td-p/124631).

Comment: Hi pbattisson, Last time i was able to import web service. Now i am trying to call service by passing xml request. but i am getting error in response xml. Can you please help in this problem. I am using soapUI and i have set credential in request header.

Response :  <soapenv:Fault> <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.</faultstring>